# Draw custom grid in Blender view

Tags: python, api, blender

I'm trying to add a custom grid that will be drawn in blender's viewport, just like default grid.
The problem is, i dont understand how should i continuously run the draw code, and how should i attach it to a button the right way.

Here i have the drawing code:

```
def create_batch(self, context):
    self.shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('3D_UNIFORM_COLOR')
    self.batch = batch_for_shader(self.shader, 'LINES', {'pos': [(0,0,0), (1,0,0)]})
        
def draw_callback(self, context):
    self.shader.bind()
    self.shader.uniform_float('color', context.scene.cdtrk_grid.color)
    self.batch.draw(self.shader)
```

and here is the property class

```
class CDTRKGridProps(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    enabled         : bpy.props.BoolProperty (
        name        = 'enabled',
        default     = False
    )

    color           : bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty (
        name        = 'color',
        subtype     = 'COLOR',
        default     = (0.13, 0.25, 0.03)
    )

    def register():
        bpy.types.Scene.cdtrk_grid = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=CDTRKGridProps)
```

I tried creating an operator which would run the draw code, but im not sure where should i call the operator so it works from the start, and i didn't understand how to make it run everytime and not once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer, though i'm not sure if it's the correct way in terms of performance. Getting a shader everytime seems wrong.

```
def register():
    handle = bpy.types.SpaceView3D.draw_handler_add(
             draw_callback, (), 'WINDOW', 'POST_VIEW')

def draw_callback():
    if bpy.context and bpy.context.area:
        settings = bpy.context.scene.cdtrk_grid

        if settings.enabled:
            shader = gpu.shader.from_builtin('3D_SMOOTH_COLOR')
            batch = batch_for_shader(shader, 'LINES', {'pos': [(0,0,0), (1,0,0)], 
                                                'color': [(1,0,0, 1), (0,1,0, 1)]})

            shader.bind()
            batch.draw(shader)
```